# After the Automapper mapping where objects go to null values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper, asp.net-boilerplate

```
 public class CreateOrEditOwnerDetailInput : IInputDto
    {
        [Required]
        public OwnerDetailEditDto OwnerDetail { get; set; }
    }

    [AutoMap(typeof(OwnerDetail))]
    public class OwnerDetailEditDto
    {
        public const int MaxLength = 50;
        public const int NotesMaxLength = 300;

        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(MaxLength)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [MaxLength(MaxLength)]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public OwnerContactDetailDto ContactDetail { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public AdditionalAddressDto AdditionalAddress { get; set; }

    }



 [Table("IpOwnerDetails")]
    public class OwnerDetail : FullAuditedEntity
    {
        public const int MaxLength = 50;
        public const int NotesMaxLength = 300;

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(MaxLength)]
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(MaxLength)]
        public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("AdditionalAddressId")]
        public virtual AdditionalAddress AdditionalAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual int AdditionalAddressId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ContactDetailId")]
        public virtual ContactDetail ContactDetail { get; set; }
        public virtual int ContactDetailId { get; set; }


    }

public class OwnerContactDetailDto : FullAuditedEntityDto
    {
        public const int NumberMaxLength = 20;

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(NumberMaxLength)]
        public string MainPhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(NumberMaxLength)]
        public string HomePhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ContactDetailType Type { get; set; }
    }

  public class AdditionalAddressDto : FullAuditedEntityDto, IOutputDto
    {
        public const int MaxLength = 50;

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(MaxLength)]
        public string StreetNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public AddressType Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CityId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int StateId { get; set; }


    }

Mapper.CreateMap<AdditionalAddress, AdditionalAddressDto>()
              .ReverseMap()
              .ForMember(additionalAddress => additionalAddress.Id, options => options.Ignore());

            Mapper.CreateMap<ContactDetail, OwnerContactDetailDto>()
              .ReverseMap()
              .ForMember(contactDetail => contactDetail.Id, options => options.Ignore());


 public async Task<int?> EditOwnerDetailAsync(CreateOrEditOwnerDetailInput input)
        {
            var ownerDetail = await _ownerDetailRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == input.OwnerDetail.Id);
            input.OwnerDetail.MapTo(ownerDetail);//after this it goes null
            await _ownerDetailRepository.UpdateAsync(ownerDetail);
            return input.OwnerDetail.Id;

        }
```

**Image url :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DMsK.jpg

**Q :** After the mapping inside the `EditOwnerDetailAsync` method where both `AdditionalAddress` and  `ContactDetail` goes to `null`.Could you tell me why ? Please see the image for more info.

**Exception :**

```
    ERROR 2015-11-20 17:56:18,666 [26   ] lers.Filters.AbpExceptionFilterAttribute - System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while 
updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> 
System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the 
entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the 
FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_dbo.IpOwnerDetails_dbo.IpAdditionalAddresses_AdditionalAddressId". The 
conflict occurred in database "IP", table "dbo.IpAdditionalAddresses", column 'Id'.
    The statement has been terminated.
```

**NOTE :** The strange thing here is when I bring the debug pointer back to the `input.OwnerDetail.MapTo(ownerDetail);` line (2nd time) then it fills data for the `AdditionalAddress` and `ContactDetail` objects.How can It be happened ?

Comment: Is `MapTo` an extension method? Can you show the code in it?

Comment: @stuartd Yes,Please see this doc..http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Transfer-Objects

Comment: The extension method [appears to be using the correct overload of Map (the one that does not overwrite the existing object)](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/master/src/Abp.AutoMapper/AutoMapper/AutoMapExtensions.cs), so it isn't that.

Comment: @stuartd Sorry I couldn't get that ?

Comment: Well, a common cause of this problem is calling `existingObject = Mapper.Map(source)` - which creates a new object, overwriting the existing one. However `MapTo` seems to call `Mapper.Map(source, existingObject )` which preserves the existing values. Are you using the most recent version of Abp.AutoMapper?

Comment: @stuartd Ver : 4.0.4.0

Comment: @stuartd Could you tell me why this is happening? Did you see the above image ?

Comment: @stuartd I have updated the exception which it gives due to `null` objects.Please see that too...

Answer (score -1):

The mappings with `AutoMapper` are done either by convention or by configuration. For nested properties, suppose you have two have nested properties as source of your map like

```
public class OuterSrc{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public InnerSrc Source{get; set;} 
}
public class InnerSrc{
   public string Title{get; set;}
}
```

and for destination you have a single class like

```
public class Destination
{
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
}
```

If you define a default mapping from `OuterSrc` to `Destination` would `Title` form `InnerSrc` map to `Title` property of `Destination`. The plain answer is no because, the properties are not named according to `AutoMapper` conventions.
So in this case, I have couple of options. Firstly, I can change the property name to match conventions like

```
public class Destination{
   public string Name{get;set;} // as earlier
   public string SourceTitle{get;set;} // see the change here. Source is //property in `OuterSrc` and `Title` is property in `InnerSrc`. I just merged //them
}
```

If you think, this solution is not viable, you can define such mappings in configurations like

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<OuterSrc, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Title,
               opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Source.Title));
```

By doing this, your mapper will know how to map your inner properties.

Comment: Yes,But on above scenario where all are identical no ? Why still it gives `null` ?